# ASP.Net solution how to avoid generate deps.json file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

Does the *.deps.json file adds any value in production? If it doesnt, can anyone help how to avoid generate this file.

Currently i am using post build event to delete this file and getting build error when i run the solution.

```
del $(OutDir)*.deps.json
```

Thanks